# How to hide classes from my jar or aar file?

Tags: android, gradle

I am developing a library right now. Mini structure is like

```
AwesomeLib
  ----Core
        -Engine
        -Manager
        -...
  ----Services
        -AServices
        -BServices
        -.....
```

I do not want some parts to be accessed like Engine or Manager inside Core package by client. But i needed them at Services part. So i cant use default class. Also i dont want to collect all classes in same package.

Note: I give jar-aar file to client only.

Note 2: I dont want to protect my code. Just want to use encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

If it is encapsulation you are after, try this:

- Make the `Engine` and `Manager` private
- Create a public interface for each of them (make them implement the interfaces)
- For each of the interfaces (or each logical group) create a **Factory** class, which will create the `Object`, but only return it as its interface.

This way all the implementation details will be hidden behind an interface, encapsulating all the logic.

The client will be able to use the **Factory** to create an implementation of the interface, but will not know the implementation details nor the rest of the system logic, so it will be useless to them.

Comment: Well, your answer totally true sir but i also wonder is gradle side solution possible for hiding transitive dependencies. I know ClassLoader needs them to use but it feels like it's not as smart as it should be.

Comment: But in this case it is not really a dependency, is it? Just a parallel package. So I would say you should go for an architectural approach.